# How to sort xDocument node by name

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I've faced with problem where I have to sort the XDocument by node name. Example

```
<contact>
    <email></email>
    <address></address>
    <name></name> 
</contact>
```

And I want to get

```
<contact>
    <address></address>
    <email></email>
    <name></name>
</contact>
```

Thank you for your help.

I've tried to use

```
var ab = xdoc.Descendants("contact");
            var s = from abs in ab
                    orderby abs.Name.ToString() descending
                    select abs;
```

but the result staying the same

Comment: and what stopped you in the middle of solving this task? See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've looked a lot of stackoverflow pages but didn't find the right answer

Comment: There are more than one contact?

Comment: no, only one contact

Comment: yep, 'dtb' answer helps me. Also 'Martin Honnen' gave the right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace the child nodes with the ordered nodes:

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(@"<contact>
    <email></email>
    <address></address>
    <name></name> 
</contact>");
            doc.Root.ReplaceNodes(doc.Root.Elements().OrderBy(el => el.Name.LocalName));
```